# Dynamic reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 <modal v-for="(data,key) in passedInData" :key="data.id" :ref="'modal' + key">    
 <img src="~/assets/images/lock.svg" @click="openModal(key)"  style="cursor:pointer" > 

    openModal: function(id) {
      let modal = this.$refs['modal' + id];
      let index = 'modal' + id;
      console.log(this.$refs['modal' + id]);
      console.log(this.$refs[index].showModal); 
    }
```

I am looping through a component by using a v-for and give a dynamic reference to each element.
On click of a button I call a function that return the right reference if I do console.log(this.$refs[index]), however when I try to call a method by doing: console.log(this.$refs[index].showModal), which in this case showModal is a method in a child component, it returns undefined.

Comment: uses `<modal v-for="(data,key) in passedInData" :key="data.id" ref="modal">`, then access by `this.$refs.model[index]`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by doing:
this.$refs[index][0].showModal();